# Custom Tooltip Formatting

Tags: c, windows, winapi, tooltip

I am working in plain old native C on Windows.  No other platforms, no C++.  (Yes, I'm a dinosaur.)

I am trying to find an example of what I think of as an "owner draw tooltip control" but that does not appear to exist.  At least not for the standard Windows tooltip control.  I have tried to search for a library or source that implements a custom tooltip control, but all I can find is things that extend controls in .NET (or in other environments that are not where I am working.)

My hope is to support markdown (or something like it) for the text in the tooltip window.  Mostly, I want to clearly differentiate the title from the content, and have some limited formatting of the content (bold, italics, color, and columns, mostly.)

I don't expect a full solution here, I am just hoping that someone else has already found a solution and can point me to where they found it.  Please?

Comment: You are looking for a "custom drawn" tooltip, not owner drawn. As it stands your questions is probably too broad; but check this page (it's in C as an added bonus): https://www.stevenengelhardt.com/2007/08/29/custom-drawn-win32-tooltips/

Comment: And there is the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/nm-customdraw-tooltip).

Comment: @TheNextman, you should post your comment as an answer and I will accept and vote for it.  That's exactly what I was looking for.  Early in my searching I hit something that made me believe that I found only change the overall font colors, but not draw the entire tip myself.  Thanks for the mental re-adjustment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tooltips cannot be owner drawn, but they can be "custom drawn".

Custom drawn Win32 controls allow you to override the built-in drawing by receiving and responding to the `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` notification. You can read about custom draw [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/about-custom-draw).

You can refer to the specific documentation on the tooltip control, see:

[NM_CUSTOMDRAW (tooltip) notification code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/nm-customdraw-tooltip)

Finally, [here](https://www.stevenengelhardt.com/2007/08/29/custom-drawn-win32-tooltips/) is a good tutorial demonstrating the whole thing in C.

Comment: It never occurred to me to allow the original tip to draw itself using the same foreground/background (effectively drawing invisibly) and then drawing what I want right over that, but that's how the example works.  Thanks!