# Missing Windows Tooltip Notification Messages?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, tooltip

First, I'm working in native C, using VS2019 -- no C++ -- so an answer that tells me to use some C++ function that hides everything from me will not be helpful.

OK, here's my situation:

I have a program using what is *effectively* a tracking tooltip (but it doesn't work if it actually has the `TTF_TRACKING` style flag!).  They pop up anywhere I want, when I want, and go away when I want.  I can control the foreground/background colors, use the system tip icons, and even have a bold title line.  I use newlines to make them multiline.  All of that works great.

I would like to go one step further and actually convert them to custom draw.  The documentation says that I should process the `NM_CUSTOMDRAW` notifications.

Unfortunately, my program receives **NO NOTIFICATIONS** for the tool window.  Ever.

I've put debug output in the `WM_NOTIFY` handler, and even check in the program's message pump for any `WM_NOTIFY` messages for any window being detected, but there are NONE.

When I send the `TTM_ADDTOOL` message, I set the `toolinfo.hwnd` member to the tooltip window's handle.  If I change that to the owning window's handle, then the tips never display and I STILL never get `WM_NOTIFY` messages.

I've tried adding the `TTF_SUBCLASS` flag to the `TOOLINFO` flags for `TTM_ADDTOOL`, but that seems to have no effect on the behavior.

Basically, I create a 'normal' tooltip that is inactive.  When I get a `WM_MOUSEHOVER` over something on my screen that should have a tip, I send these messages to the tip to get it displayed in the correct location:

```
TTM_SETMARGIN
TTM_UPDATETIPTEXT
TTM_SETTITLE
TTM_SETTIPBKCOLOR
TTM_SETTIPTEXTCOLOR
TTM_TRACKACTIVATE
TTM_TRACKPOSITION
```

When I want to hide the tip, I send `TTM_TRACKACTIVATE` again, but with the flag set to FALSE.

I started with the example that I was given a few years ago from my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583767/), and even with that code to create and add the tool, I get no `WM_NOTIFY` messages.  Ever.

The example only barely works, too.  It uses `TTF_SUBCLASS`, and the tip seems to appear at random locations, and even a single CLICK event causes the tip to stop displaying until the example is restarted.

I would prefer to skip the subclass and use `TrackMouseEvent()` for the hover and leave events, and then send a `TTM_POPUP` to display the tip when needed (and `TTM_POP` to remove it later).  If I make any of those changes, the example ceases to display any tip at all.  Sigh.

Can anyone explain the precise requirements that I must meet so that my main program (the tip owner) receives notifications for the tooltip?  I *think* that if I could actually get the notifications, I *might* be able to get everything else to work.

Before someone simply states:

> Notification messages are sent to the window specified in the `TOOLINFO` structure when you add the tool to the tooltip.

Please be aware that statement is simply NOT [always] TRUE.  I have verified that my main window's `hwnd` **is** the same value that I am using in my `TOOLINFO` struct whenever that struct is required by a `TTM_` message, yet I NEVER receive `WM_NOTIFY` messages in my main window's message loop.  So there is more to this than that overly simplistic answer.

Can anyone direct me to some actual documentation about custom-drawn tool tips, if such a thing exists in any non-proprietary form?  Otherwise, I may need to consider just creating a little popup window of my own to *act* like a tooltip instead, but without all of the bizarre (to me) quirks and inter-dependencies and what not.

**EDIT**  OK, I've created a test project from [Steven Engelhardt's sample code](https://www.stevenengelhardt.com/2007/08/29/custom-drawn-win32-tooltips/) that may be downloaded from [cdtip.zip](https://www.svalli.com/files/cdtips.zip) and added some changes of my own.  When the symbol `_StevesChanges_` (first line in main.c) is defined, my code is included in the build.  There are two strange (to me) differences between the behavior with my code and the original:

1. If I don't use OPAQUE background mode, then the original tool tip text is still visible, despite the text/background being set the same in the WM_NOTIFY.
2. With my changes compiled in, the tip only appears *every other time* that the mouse hovers.  The WM_MOUSEHOVER event is received and does the same stuff, but only triggers the WM_NOTIFY messages on alternate calls.

Also, with the original code (my changes not included), if the tip is hidden because it expires, then it will never reappear, which is not useful.  *AND* in the original code, the tip appears almost immediately, even when the mouse is *moving*, so the example is not particularly good.

**EDIT 2**

I think that what I'm asking is for information about dependencies and/or interactions that tooltips have on other parts of my program.  For example, if I process WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED and don't forward it to the default handler, then I will *never* receive WM_SIZE messages. When I changed the example to use DrawText() to measure and draw the tip text, other behaviors changed, too, like the original text showing through and even when the tip would display.  I may be consuming a window message that I need to forward in order to make the tips work (in my actual production code).  I can find nothing about any such interactions, but I need to know what they are.  Or else I need *much* more detailed information about tooltip controls, the TOOLINFO structure and their interaction with Windows.

But, I think I'm going to give up on this.  Three years of research into this (off and on) has yet to produce the desired information, so I'm not likely to find it now.  I was just hoping to avoid creating my own custom tool tip window handler, but it seems that is the path I must follow.  Unless someone is willing to share a working example of a native C project that includes a tool tip that is activated when the main program receives a WM_MOUSEHOVER and dismissed by a mouse move or click, *and* is custom drawn, then this question should remain unanswered.

Comment: Have you seen [Custom-Drawn Win32 Tooltips](https://www.stevenengelhardt.com/2007/08/29/custom-drawn-win32-tooltips/) yet?

Comment: Hard to know what could be wrong without seeing code. You say *"When I send the TTM_ADDTOOL message, I set the toolinfo.hwnd member to the tooltip window's handle."* - well this is wrong to start with. That HWND needs to be the owner window, which is where the notification messages are sent. Later on in your post you contradict this, but without seeing your code it's hard to know exactly what it is you're doing.

Comment: Could you please provie the sample to help us reproduce the issue? For more details about custom draw controls, you could refer to the Docs: [About Custom Draw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/about-custom-draw) ,[NM_CUSTOMDRAW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-customdraw-tooltip). And you could refer to the thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583767/custom-tooltip-formatting

Comment: @RemyLebeau That link is exactly what was referenced in my original post (linked in my post here) and was the basis for my code.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Sorry, I wasn't clear:  I tried using BOTH the tooltip's hwnd and the owner's hwnd in the toolinfo.hwnd member, but NEITHER causes the owner to receive WM_NOTIFY messages.  However, using the owner hwnd also causes my tips to never appear _at all_.  I will try to put some code together that is less than 10,000 lines (smile)

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT I have read all of those things.  In fact, I _wrote_ (and ref'd in my post above) the 3rd one.  None of them address why, following the minimal info about getting WM_NOTIFY that is published by Microsoft, I might still never receive WM_NOTIFY.  That's what I'm looking for.  The existing documentation is extremely vague unless one is doing _exactly_ (and **only**) what the examples do instead of what the docs _imply_ that one _could do_ (i.e. actually custom drawing a tracking tool tip that is displayed when the application requests it without associating the tip with a control.)

Comment: "However, using the owner hwnd also causes my tips to never appear at all" - I suspect that's where your problem is. Fix that, and it'll probably solve the WM_NOTIFY issue as well.

Comment: I was unable to get my actual application to use custom drawn tool tips reliably, so I created my own tooltip library to do it for me.  I still have some text measuring and placement issues, but it basically works and may provide a starting point for someone with more skill than I.  You can find it at https://github.com/nurbles/FancyTips (along with a test driver to see it working.)